# How do I retrieve the proxied class from the proxy class?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate with proxies, and I get objects belonging to classes such as `test.DBUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$40e99a2d`.

Is there a Hibernate method to retrieve the base class (`test.DBUser` in this case) from the proxied *class*? I know about `Hibernate.getClass()`, but it takes an `Object`, while I'm looking for a method which takes as input a `Class`.

Comment: Why do you need this in the first place? The proxy extends your base class, so every method you can call on an instance of the base class can also be called on the proxy, and will return do the same thing.

Comment: I was researching this for another question on passing hibernate proxied objects to the GSON library. The library makes some calls passing implementors the proxy `Class`, and only later the proxy `Object`, and I wanted to be able to start doing something with the `Class`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out, it is easier than I thought: just call `getSuperclass()` on the proxied class to obtain the unproxied, original class. I'm not sure how general this is, but it appears to work.

Answer (score 14):

While I really like the simplicity of the approach posted by Flavio, I can't use it in production code unless it's documented as supported. Also, if you call `.getImplementation()` on the `LazyInitializer`, it will force the initialization of the proxy if it isn't already, which is a negative performance impact. I've come up with this approach which addresses both of these concerns:

```
public static Class<?> getClassForHibernateObject(Object object) {
  if (object instanceof HibernateProxy) {
    LazyInitializer lazyInitializer =
        ((HibernateProxy) object).getHibernateLazyInitializer();
    return lazyInitializer.getPersistentClass();
  } else {
    return object.getClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good call, a test using QueryCount proves this does not hydrate the proxy. Using in production, thanks

Comment: Sadly in my cas i get à super class instead of the real one

Answer (score 1):

Classes like `test.DBUser$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$40e99a2d` are [dynamic proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html). The concept of "real class behind" does not make much sense in most cases. Every single time a proxy is created, it can be instance of any class as Hibernate defines it.

What you are **really** asking for is static `Map` of `{ Class<Proxy>, Class<RealObject>}`. I don't believe there's such a thing nor I believe there's a need for this. Just look at the source of `Hibernate.getClass()`:

```
339     public static Class getClass(Object proxy) {
340     if ( proxy instanceof HibernateProxy ) {
341         return ( ( HibernateProxy ) proxy ).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
342                 .getImplementation()
343                 .getClass();
344     }
345     else {
346         return proxy.getClass();
347     }
348 }
```

It would be much much cheaper to do a static map lookup to get the real class, but Hibernate goes all the way to the lazy initializer to get the implementing class.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this.  It looks to me like your code is right-on.  I like that you revealed that this is the actual Hibernate code.

Comment: Here are the links to what you suggest: [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#getClass-java.lang.Object-)
[src](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/Hibernate.java#L87)

Comment: Yes should be the correct answer as it will work all the time even with inheritance case

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method. You will need to write a helper class yourself in order to retrieve the wrapped object and thus the class information from inside the proxy. If you only need the object in the given scenario, try to remove all the lazy loading. Hibernate should then give you the plain object.

Consider trying not to need the object. Maybe you can redesign the application so that you do not need it, for example by adding a field containing the desired information at runtime.