# Hibernate JPA equals POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity POJO, that has **item** and **location** properties used for hashcode and equals.

```
List<POJO> pojos = pojoRepository.findAll();
```

Then I create a lookup POJO object,

```
POJO pojo = new POJO(item, location);
```

but when I try to execute `pojos.contains(pojo)`, it returns false.
So I put a debug info in the pojo `equals` method.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        System.err.println("xxxxxxxxxx");
        System.err.println(getClass());
        System.err.println(obj.getClass());
        System.err.println("xxxxxxxxxx");
        return false;
    }
```

output returns

```
xxxxxxxxxx
class com.demo.entity.Pojo
class com.demo.entity.Pojo_$$_jvst83f_19
xxxxxxxxxx
```

How to make it equal? I also tried `obj instanceof Pojo` and still returns false.

Comment: You could use the code to get the real object https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546064/4725592

Comment: this is kind of neat, but would add additional checking if dynamic proxy.

Comment: Try my blog
[Impact of proxy on equals and hashCode](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2012/01/23/impact-of-proxy-on-equals-and-hashcode/)

Answer (score 1):

That is because hibernate internally creates `proxy` class. What query returns is proxied instance that mimics entity type. Thats why it is not `Pojo` but inner proxy class `_jvst83f_19`

Skip class comparision and compare only properties.

You can try something like that as well:

```
getClass().inInstance(obj)
```

Comment: yes, but what would be the work here in order for it to be equal?

Comment: hmm.. that would double my effort on the development, as all entities are generated using eclipse.

Comment: depends on the approach. you could use hack like using `unwrap` to retrieve actual proxied object, but that is a hack. IMHO you should only rely on generated hash codes.

Comment: Other more viable approach would be to use boilerplate code teardown tool like `lombok` it can generate what you need on the fly .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use *instanceof* instead of comparison  *getClass*.

Secondly, use getters for fields. In this situation hibernate resolves data from database.

You can try this implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof ThisType)) return false;

    ThisType other = (ThisType) o;

    return getPrimaryKey() != null ? getPrimaryKey().equals(other.getPrimaryKey()) : other.getPrimaryKey() == null;
}
```

*ThisType* - your class type

*getPrimaryKey()* -  getter for "primary key" of this class. Usually annotated by @Id