(Java) How should I implement code for 2 semantically identical entities that need to be stored in different DB tables?
We are an E-commerce company and so far, we have been using an entity called DeliveryAddressEntity to represent address data stored when we receive orders. I am trying to add support for BillingAddressEntity, which would have the exact same fields as DeliveryAddress, but I need it to be stored in a different table. So far I have included an abstract class, called AddressEntity:
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@FieldNameConstants
public class AddressEntity extends AbstractEntity\<Long\> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;
    
    @Column(name = "address_line_1", length = 500)
    private String addressLine1;
    
    @Column(name = "address_line_2", length = 500)
    private String addressLine2;

}

etc...
from which DeliveryAddress and BillingAddress inherit from:

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "billing_address")
    @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
    @AuditOverride(forClass = AbstractEntity.class)
    @FieldNameConstants
    public class BillingAddressEntity extends AddressEntity {

}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "delivery_address")
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@AuditOverride(forClass = AbstractEntity.class)
@FieldNameConstants
public class DeliveryAddressEntity extends AddressEntity {

}

The problem I'm facing is that a lot of the relevant business logic is written for the DeliveryAddressEntity class, and refactoring it is proving to be tough. For example there is a method:

@Override
public DeliveryAddressEntity toDeliveryAddressEntity(OrderMessage orderMessage) {
DeliveryAddressEntity deliveryAddress = orderMessageMapper.toAddressEntity(
orderMessage.getDeliveryAddress());
return deliveryAddress;
}

I would like to simply reuse this method for BillingAddressEntity, however this is not possible due to it returning the wrong type. I have tried different ways of refactoring like using the AddressMessage class as both abstract and non abstract. However, I can't help feeling there is a simpler solution. The two types of Addresses are literally identical; they just need to saved to different DB tables. Perhaps I need a middle-man class To perform all the business logic on, and only at the point of saving to the DB I need to convert to the corresponding entity?
Thanks
Tried to refactor methods a lot, but seems hard keeping in mind I want to avoid repeated code, and also altering Objects passed to methods as a parameter. For example I tried to extract the setter methods from

public DeliveryAddressEntity toDeliveryAddressEntity(DeliveryAddressMessage request) {
if (request == null) {
return null;
}
DeliveryAddressEntity deliveryAddress = new DeliveryAddressEntity();
deliveryAddress.setAddressLine1(request.getAddressLine1());
deliveryAddress.setAddressLine2(request.getAddressLine2());
deliveryAddress.setCity(request.getCity());
deliveryAddress.setState(request.getState());
deliveryAddress.setCountryCode(request.getCountryCode());
deliveryAddress.setHouseNumberOrName(request.getHouseNumberOrName());
deliveryAddress.setPostcode(request.getPostcode());
return deliveryAddress;
}

public BillingAddressEntity toBillingAddressEntity(DeliveryAddressMessage request) {
if (request == null) {
return null;
}
BillingAddressEntity billingAddress = new BillingAddressEntity();
billingAddress.setAddressLine1(request.getAddressLine1());
billingAddress.setAddressLine2(request.getAddressLine2());
billingAddress.setCity(request.getCity());
billingAddress.setState(request.getState());
billingAddress.setCountryCode(request.getCountryCode());
billingAddress.setHouseNumberOrName(request.getHouseNumberOrName());
billingAddress.setPostcode(request.getPostcode());
return billingAddress;
}`your text`



What is the challange in returning the AddressEntity for all methods which are already returning the DeliveryAddressEntity? After this you can convert to the respective DTO.

Either use the base class as already suggested or introduce an interface. Matter of taste.

@rahulP should I convert by casting before I save the entities ?

You can easily determine the object class name before saving the entity, but remember, Hibernate works with proxies, and it won't work if you directly use instanceOf or getClass() method directly on the proxy. Check the below link to efficiently use it for all cases to determine the exact class name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540923/how-do-i-retrieve-the-proxied-class-from-the-proxy-class
